# SNMP: hrSystemUptime.0: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> hrSystemUptime)

Tags: docker, snmp, alpine

I get the error in the title when I issue the following command.

```
$  snmpget -v3 -u edgeos-snmpd-user -l authPriv -a SHA -x AES -A authPhrase -X privPhrase 192.168.x.x hrSystemUptime.0
hrSystemUptime.0: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> hrSystemUptime)
```

If I enter the same command on the target system (192.168.x.x), I get a valid result.

```
# snmpget -v3 -u edgeos-snmpd-user -l authPriv -a SHA -x AES -A authPhrase -X privPhrase localhost hrSystemUptime.0
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemUptime.0 = Timeticks: (1362660) 3:47:06.60
```

The client is an Ubuntu 18.04.1 based Docker container and the target is an Alpine-based Linux device.

I have installed `snmp-mibs-downloader` in the container and the `hrSystemUptime` entry exists in `"/var/lib/snmp/mibs/ietf/HOST-RESOURCES-MIB`.

```
-- The Host Resources System Group

hrSystemUptime OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX     TimeTicks
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS     current
    DESCRIPTION
        "The amount of time since this host was last
        initialized.  Note that this is different from
        sysUpTime in the SNMPv2-MIB [RFC1907] because
        sysUpTime is the uptime of the network management
        portion of the system."
    ::= { hrSystem 1 }
```

However, it doesn't seem to be searching this directory.

```
$ net-snmp-config --default-mibdirs
/home/edge/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
```

I copied `HOST-RESOURCES-MIB` to `/home/edge/.snmp/mibs` but it made no difference.

What do I have to do in the container to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `snmp` package installs `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf`:

```
# As the snmp packages come without MIB files due to license reasons, loading
# of MIBs is disabled by default. If you added the MIBs you can reenable
# loading them by commenting out the following line.
mibs :
```

Commenting out the last line resolves problem as described by the comment in the file.  Removing `snmp.conf` entirely has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when trying to get telegraf working through docker to poll a router for various stats.

The file it seemed to want, HOST-RESOURCES-MIB, was in a hard-linked folder (dunno the right terminology, but with ls -l, it was a different colour with the linked dest. specificed), but even with the correct volumes in the docker config and right /usr/* permissions, no go.

Spent half the night messing with it, but eventually it worked when i specified the two hardlinked folders as volumes in docker:

```
 - /var/lib/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:ro
 - /var/lib/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:ro
```

Pretty sure its just me being an idiot and maybe not installing things in the right order, but the more I think the more it seems that its a docker/ubuntu issue- should work out of the box right?

Im a total linux noob, so prob an easy explanation for what I messed up, who knows. Hope this helps someone